How to reset an item in a CollectionView natively in .NET MAUI
I am working on a .net maui project involving the need to dive into native code to fix a well-known issue with the collection views not resizing when, say, expanding a section in a custom accordion on ios to view a nested collection view (surprise surprise).
I am stuck on getting each section item in a UICollectionView to reload when data has been updated so that the cell size can correctly update when data changes. Here is the code that I have so far for the OnItemSelected command when selecting an item in the ollection view MAUI control:

        public void OnSectionTapped(ItemObject section)
        {
            section.Expanded = !section.Expanded;
#if IOS
            var baseView = MainCollectionView.Handler.PlatformView;

            if(baseView != null)
            {
                var view = baseView as UIView;

                if(view != null)
                {
                    var subViewItemIsCollecitonView = view.Subviews[0] is UICollectionView;

                    if(subViewItemIsCollecitonView)
                    {
                        var iosCollectionView = (view.Subviews[0] as UICollectionView);
// This is the section where I am stuck
                        var items = iosCollectionView.GetIndexPathsForSelectedItems();

                        if(items != null)
                        {
                            var itemArr = items.ToArray();
                            var item = itemArr.FirstOrDefault();
                             
                            //iosCollectionView.ReloadItems(items.ToArray());
//This is the section where I am stuck
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
#endif
        }

I've looked at the iOS docs, but I guess I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around getting the section and item indexes for the IndexPath to reload each item. I do apologize for the stupid question since this is my first time having to do this. Thanks.

The MAUI team randomly closes this issue, (it is up for like a year or so...). The same issue you can see at community toolkit. https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues/1670 And it has some sort of solution. Never tested it, cannot say if it is gonna work.

No No! This looks good! I've been looking for some form of implementation for the custom renderer route. It is a little off topic for this question, but I'll take it! Thanks H.A.H! It really is a shame how much they just don't care at MS.

I would like to say that if someone does know how to answer my question, that would be great. I'm still leaving it up.

@H.A.H. would you know how to write a similar implementation to the OnAttachedListenerEffect to "to trigger an event when a view gets attached to the window"? I understand everything else in this code, but I can't figure out a similar way to how this could be done.

I have only superficial knowledge on Effects. I can only guess, that he has "Action OnAttachedToWindow" in this class, that gets called when OnAttached.  You will also need to find the closest ancestor of a given class. Anyway, the whole dark magic is inside the handler, and its "RaiseViewCellSizeChangedEvent". Where the UITableView calls begin/end updates. (My point being - focus on it, skip the rest)
